# json file calling repeatedly in angular 5

Tags: angular

Here iam trying to call json file using http.get method but this file is calling multiple times and in json file have multiple urls.please have any suggestion share it.below i share the code and screen shot.

```
getUrls () {
    console.log("getting in logser")
     this.http.get('assets/api_urls.json').subscribe((res) => {
         this.Api_urls= res;
         // console.log('newUrls',this.Api_urls)

       },(error)=>{
         // this.spinner.hide()
         // alert("Failed to load Urls")
       });
  }
```

Here's the Screenshot image

[image]

Comment: Where and how your `getUrls` function is called?

Comment: I'm guessing you call `getUrls` from the template. Call it from a lifecycle interface method like `ngOnInit instead.

Comment: you must be binding this method call somewhere in your template binding

Comment: iam calling in constructor constructor(private http:HttpClient,public localStorage:LocalStorageService) {
    if(this.localStorage.get('app_mode')){
      // this.baseUrl = this.localStorage.get('app_mode');
    }
    this.getUrls();
    
  }

Comment: Thanks all of you for suggestion.but iam not understand when i calling in constructor this method it calling multiple time but when i changed to ngOnit().it working fine why?

Answer (score 0):

***Please try like this***

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
         var obj;
         this.getUrls().subscribe(data => obj=data, error => console.log(error));
    }

    public getUrls(): Observable<any> {
         return this.http.get('assets/api_urls.json')
                         .map((res:any) => res.json())
                         .catch((error:any) => console.log(error));

     }
```

Comment: Hello Shubham please check it

Comment: Or if don't like to map it into json then please use httpclient

Comment: can you please accept and  and up vote it if your issue is fixed

Answer (score 0):

First Just call your method inside your ngOnInit

```
  ngOnInit()
  {
   this.getUrls();    
  }
```

Then, call the function like this

```
getUrls()
{   
   this.http.get('assets/api_urls.json',{headers:headers})


  .map(res => res.json())
  .catch((error: any) =>{return Observable.throw(error)} )
        .subscribe(
          data => {
              console.log(data);
              this.Api_urls= data;
         },

        error{

         }

}
```

Comment: why is calling mutiple times when i called to constructor.